# angularjs with typescript - cannot access $scope

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am building an angularjs app using typescript, and have just created my first controller - the problem is that I'm having a hard time using `ng-model` with an object on it.

This is what it all looks like;

`app.ts`

```
((): void => {
   'use strict';
   angular.module('app', ['app.core','app.widgets','app.services']);
})();
```

`app.services.ts`

> User Service is defined here and is not relevant to this sample

'app.widgets.ts`

```
module app.widgets {
   'use strict';
   interface IUserController {
      User: app.services.IUser;
   }

   class UserController implements IUserController {
      User: app.services.IUser;

      static $inject = ['$scope', 'app.services.UserService'];
      constructor(scope: any, userService: app.services.IUserService){
         var vm = this;
         userService.Find().then((user: app.services.IUser): void => {
            scope.User = user; // this is the offending line
         });
      }
   }

   angular.module('app.widgets').controller('app.widgets.UserController', UserController);
}
```

I attempt to call this in my HTML like this;

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="app.widgets.UserController">
   {{ User.UserName }}
</body>
```

Or ..

```
<h1 ng-model="User.UserName"></h1>
```

## Update

I haven't quite solved it completely, but I have made more progress

```
interface IUserControllerScope extends angular.IScope {
   User: app.services.IUser;
}

class UserController {
    static $inject = ['$scope', 'app.services.UserService'];
    constructor($scope: IUserControllerScope, userService: app.services.IUserService) {
       var _this = $scope;
       userService.Find().then((user: app.services.IUser): void => {
             _this.User = user;
          });
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: your constructor is asking for `scope`, but you are injecting `$scope`.  the `$` is essential

Comment: I tried that, it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because `scope` is undefined. Try changing `scope` to `$scope`.  Then you can access user like this

```
$scope.User = user
```

Comment: I actually made a bit of progress with that, though it wasn't the sole answer.

Comment: The answer turned out to be that I needed to both declare `$scope` and I also needed the `var _this = $scope` so that I could add things to it. I had to make an interface that extended `angular.IScope` to do this and get type safety.

Answer (score 1):

> {{ User.UserName }}

You might have a typo in this line. Try

```
<pre> {{User | json}} </pre>
```

I suspect it should be User.username

Comment: UserName is correct. It is from the Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Framework

Answer (score 1):

on neat way of doing is not to play with $scope more rather use a instance of controller to assign into a scope variable

```
class UserController implements IUserController {
  User: app.services.IUser;
  public user:any;
  static $inject = ['$scope', 'app.services.UserService'];
  constructor(scope: any, userService: app.services.IUserService){
     userService.Find().then((user: app.services.IUser): void => {
        this.User = user; // this is the offending line
     });

   //assign instance to a scope variable and access in view
   scope.vm=this
  }
 }

 angular.module('app.widgets').controller('app.widgets.UserController',      UserController);
}
```

and in view example

```
   <div>{{vm.user}}</div>
```